# How can the effects of temperature be accounted for in-situ electrical resistance corrosion monitoring?

Tags: electricity, experimental-physics, electrical-resistance

In reading the Berkeley Lab's article [Rust Never Sleeps](http://newscenter.lbl.gov/2012/09/06/rust-never-sleeps/), where research is underway investigating the use of iron oxide rust as a photovoltaic, they state:

> Rust – iron oxide – is a poor conductor of electricity

This implies that rust has a greater resistance than iron, and that resistance is reliant on the resistivity of the rust, which in turn is temperature dependent [source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/resis.html).

Ideally, samples could be brought back to a temperature-controlled environment in a lab for analysis; however, a lot of the time, corrosion (rust) samples can not be practically moved or have samples brought back to a controlled environment lab, they need to be analysed in-situ where temperatures would fluctuate.

**How can the effects of temperature be accounted for in-situ electrical resistance corrosion monitoring?**

Comment: By this, I assume you are already monitoring temperature and need to know the speed of the chemical reaction (rusting) as a function of temperature? If so, this is a question for physical chemistry. However, ballpark figures usually quote a doubling of reaction rate for every 10 degC

http://bouman.chem.georgetown.edu/S02/lect4/lect4.htm

Comment: @DirkBruere thank you for the reference! The experimental design you describe would certainly be ideal, and in a lot of cases, definitely practically possible.  However, for on the spot short-term inspections there would need to be a way to 'normalise' the temperature affected resistivity.

Comment: I would have though there would be bigger variations due to humidity. The conductivity of steel does not vary much with small changes in temp. However, rust, which is normally an insulator, would be very sensitive to adsorbing water and/or salt if this is about roads and bridges